# How do I get paginated data from a WordPress API using jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

EDITED QUESTION

I'm working on a PHP page (not in WordPress so I can't use a plugin) and I want to use AJAX to bring in blog posts (three per page) from a WordPress multisite with pagination.

There is a problem with the pagination in what is rendered on the page.

On accessing the page three posts are displayed however when clicking page two all posts are displayed. The desired behaviour is that the next three posts should be displayed.

```
<div id="paging"></div>

                   <ul class="pagination text-center" role="navigation" aria-label="Pagination" data-page="6" data-total="16"> 
 
 <li class="pagination-previous disabled" onclick="previous()">Previous<span class="show-for-sr" >page</span></li>
 
 <li class="current"><a href="#"class="page-link" data-page_number ="1" data-per-page="3" aria-label="Page 1"><span class="show-for-sr">You're on page</span> 1</a></li>
 
 <li><a href="#"class="page-link" data-page_number ="2" data-per-page="3" aria-label="Page 2">2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" class="page-link" data-page_number ="3" data-per-page="3" aria-label="Page 3">3</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" class="page-link" data-page_number ="4" data-per-page="3"  aria-label="Page 4">4</a></li>

 <li class="pagination-next" onclick="next()"><a href="#" aria-label="Next page">Next <span class="show-for-sr">page</span></a></li>
</ul>

</div>
</div> 
</div>

<script>

$( document ).ready(function() {
    myFetchPosts(1)
           }); 

 //start with page one
 // var page = 1;

function myFetchPosts(page) {    

//pass in the page number 

var page = page;

   
    // used a template literal to add the page parameter

    var api_url = `example.com/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=3&page=${page}`;

$("#results").empty();

    $.ajax({
            url: api_url,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
          //  headers: 'X-WP-Total',
            success: function(response){
            //   console.log(response.headers);
                          var len = response.length;
                for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                    var id = response[i].id;

                    var date = new Date(response[i].date_gmt);
                    var mydate = date.getDate();
                    var mymonth = date.getMonth();
                    var myyear = date.getFullYear();

                    var slug = response[i].slug;
                    var excerpt = response[i].excerpt.rendered;
                                         var link = response[i].link;

                    var tr_str =
                     
                     '<td>'+
                    '<div class="card" style="width: 250px;">' +
                    '<div class="card-divider">' + (id+1) + ' ' + slug + '</div>' +  
                    
                    '<img src="example.com/images/model.jpg">' +
                    ' <div class="card-section">' +   
                     '<p>' + excerpt + '</p>' +
                     '<h4>' +  mydate + '/' + mymonth + '/' + myyear + '</h4>' +
                      
                    
                    
                    '<a href="'  + link + ' " target="_blank">'+                   
                    '<input type="button" value="read more" style="margin-right: 15px;">' + 
                    '</input>' +
                    ' </a>' +

                     '<i onclick="myFunction(this)" class="fa fa-thumbs-up" style="margin-right: 15px;" id="' + slug + '">' +
                     '</i>'+
                      '<i onclick="myReadingList(this)" class="fa fa-book" style="margin-right: 15px;" id="' + slug + link + '">' +
                    
                     '</i>'+
                     


                    ' </div>' +
                     '</div>'+
                       '</td>' 
                        

                            
                        ;
 
                    $("#results").append(tr_str);   
                     $("#paging").append(paging);

                    // increment page so the next time this is called it will fetch the next page
                page += 1;    

            } // end of for loop
           
                   } // end of success    

        
                   
    }); // end of ajax call
    
} // end of fetch posts function
```

Comment: If this is a cross domain request check for CORS errors in the console.

Comment: I'm on a hosted site and have added wordpress to the directory (so the url of the worpress blog is the same as the site just with /wordpress on the end). There is a CORB notice in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, seems like the v2 version of wordpress API isn't allocated under wp-json address, therefore the address is not valid. According to [wordpress support](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-v2-posts-endpoint-not-working/), you must change your url to **http://example.com/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts** to make it work.